# SFINAE - Detect constructor with one argument

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, sfinae

Does anyone know how to detect a constructor with one argument? For example, this struct should have a negative result:

```
struct MyStruct
{
  MyStruct( int x, int x2 ) : y( x ) {}
  int y;
};
```

I have here a nice SFINAE check to see if a class or struct as a constructor with a specific number of arguments. Here's the one for argument count of 3:

```
template <typename T>
struct HasCtor3Args
{
  struct Any { template <typename U> operator U( void ); };

  template <typename U>
  static int32 SFINAE( decltype( U( Any( ), Any( ), Any( ) ) ) * );

  template <typename U>
  static int8 SFINAE( ... );

  static const bool value = sizeof( SFINAE<T>( NULL ) ) == sizeof( int32 );
};
```

This seems to work just fine, as the `Any` struct can convert to whatever types the parameters ought to be. However the issue is when trying to detect a constructor with just one argument. The SFINAE check seems to always return true due to defaulting `Any` to the same type as `T` thus detecting a copy constructor.

**Edit and Update**:
I've made a few attempts, none seem to be a go... This was the closest I can get, but doesn't work as it always returns true. The idea was to try and get the copy constructor to resolve instead of the first "catch all" call:

```
template <typename T>
struct HasCtor1Args
{
  struct Any
  {
    template <typename U>
    operator U( ) const;
  };

  template <typename U>
  static int32 SFINAE( decltype( U( Any( ) ) ) * );

  // Try to catch the copy ctor here
  T MakeT( void );
  template <typename U>
  static int8 SFINAE( decltype( U( MakeT( ) ) ) * );

  template <typename U>
  static int8 SFINAE( ... );

  static const bool value = sizeof( SFINAE<T>( NULL ) ) == sizeof( int32 );
};
```

I also tried using the explicit keyword, along with the = delete feature for C++11, then realized the compiler I need to use (Microsoft's) does not allow this. I also tried using std::enable_if on the conversion type U, although I ran into the error that function template parameters cannot be defaulted.

Comment: Oh, and there's [`std::is_constructible`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constructible)

Comment: For some reason, it works when the conversion operator is explicit: `template < typename U > explicit operator U() const;`. I had to look this up in the Standard, but it might be a bug in g++ 4.8.

Comment: Hmm I don't think using explicit like that will work on Microsoft's compiler though.

Comment: If there are *two* one-argument constructors, substitution will fail. I don't think there is a way around it.

Comment: n.m.'s comment also holds for multiple-parameter ctors. AFAIK the problem is the ambiguous conversion `Any` to the parameter type of `T`, e.g. `struct my_type{ my_type(int,int,int); my_type(int,int,bool); };`

Comment: What is a constructor "with one argument"? Do you mean "with one parameter" or "callable with one argument" or a combination of these?

Comment: Only accepts one parameter. I don't care about handling the case of multiple overloads of a single parameter, but just want to detect if there exist a constructor accepting one argument, non-rvalue and non-copy.

Comment: argument: "<function call expression> expression in the comma-separated list bounded by the parentheses", parameter: "object or reference declared as part of a function declaration or definition" (N3485)

Comment: @DyP Parameter then :)

Comment: Well I'd interpret that as "takes exactly one argument", or, equivalently, "has exactly one parameter" ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though n.m.'s criticism still holds, here's a version to detect a type with **only one** 1-parameter non-copy, non-move ctor. It uses SFINAE to restrict the conversion of `Any`.

Note: Additional ctors with default arguments would result in an ambiguity (e.g. `my_type(int, double=0);`. It's a very limited solution.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct HasCtor1Args
{
    struct Any
    {
      template
      <
        typename U, typename SFINAE =
          typename std::enable_if< false == std::is_same<U,T>::value, U >::type
      >
      operator U() const;
    };

    template <typename U>
    static int32_t SFINAE( decltype( U( Any( ) ) ) * );

    template <typename U>
    static int8_t SFINAE( ... );

    static const bool value = sizeof( SFINAE<T>( nullptr ) ) == sizeof( int32_t );
};


struct my_type
{
    my_type(int);
    my_type(my_type const&);
};

int main()
{
    static_assert(HasCtor1Args<my_type> :: value, "epic fail");
}
```

Comment: Ooh, wait, nvm... the parameter type would just be deduced as `Any`, I think. Same goes for default arguments. It will fail for `template<class T> C(Something<T>)`, though.

Comment: I dont see why it would fail for that. T simply becomes the Any type.

Comment: @Johannes: Ya, see my new comment above.

Comment: .... but we had the same wrong thought, Xeo :D nevertheless, the default argument problem holds though, I think.

Comment: You could overload the test function with a function whose parameter type definitely accepts the any type (but is not exactly the any type hence requiring a user defined conversion). If the call now ends up in an ambiguity (detect it by sfinae), then T has one or more one-arg accepting ctors). This will handle the ambiguities quite well (no pun intended).

Comment: Ah i forgot that the conversion function is not allowed to do two user defined conversions in a row and that your existing test works because it does a cast within the test function itself. For my approach, the conversion needs to be done by the argument->parameter pair, to get the "ambiguous user defined conversio  sequence". Too bad :-)

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I was wondering what you've been referring to :D It isn't my approach, though, I just modified the OP's approach.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Is a conversion ambiguity a failure that triggers usage of a less viable overload in SFINAE?

Comment: Trying this on Microsoft's compiler, and it seems to just fail to compile instead of performing SFINAE when Any cannot convert to type T. I'm assuming compiler bug if this works on g++. Though this works as a compile-time check, I actually need SFINAE to perform, as the point is to handle the false case during compile-time.

Comment: @RandyGaul Yes it works on g++4.8; which version of MSVC are you using?

Comment: @DyP Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler Nov 2012 CTP (v120_CTP_Nov2012) -- Seems to be the only one I could find that supports default template arguments. Maybe there's a slight variation that will actually work on this compiler? I tried guessing around but haven't gotten a working solution yet.